# Using a div tag in a repeater to display horizontally

Tags: html, css, asp.net, tags, repeater

I'm trying to display Youtube links on a page, along with a short description, and I'm using a repeater to do this.  What I have for my item template is:

```
<Item Template>
  <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" Style="margin-left:10px; margin-bottom:0px" width="800px" Font-Size="small">
    <table style="width:790px">
      <div runat="server" style="float:left; overflow:hidden; display:block">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <iframe width="370" height="210" src="<%#Eval("VideoLink") %>
          </td>
        </tr>
          <td><%#Eval("VideoDesc") %></td>
        </tr>
      </div>
    </table>
  </asp:Panel>
</ItemTemplate>
```

It displays fine, but it displays vertically.  I want it to display horizontally until it fills up the width of the table, and then begin on the following line.  I thought the div tag would do that, but it doesn't.

Also, ideally I'd like a horizontal line between the rows of video, but if that's too involved I can skip it.

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is right its better to go with a `section` element instead of `table` for your requirement and make the `div` as a `inline-block` element so that it'll be aligned properly.

```html
<Item Template>
  <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" Style="margin-left:10px; margin-bottom:0px" width="800px" Font-Size="small">
    <section style="width:790px">
      <div runat="server" style="display:inline-block">
        
            <iframe width="370" height="210" src=""></iframe>
         
      </div>
      <div runat="server" style="display:inline-block">
       
            <iframe width="370" height="210" src=""></iframe>
         
      </div>
      <div runat="server" style="display:inline-block">
       
            <iframe width="370" height="210" src=""></iframe>
         
      </div>
    </section>
  </asp:Panel>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: There is a growing number of records which will be added to my table (the table essentially just contains 2 fields; LinkName and LinkDesc).  Is the code you've posted "dynamic"; will it account for more and more records without having to be edited?

Comment: No, for testing purpose i just added 3 div's with a iframe inside it, for your case you have to replace the div's with one and iterate over it for dynamic value.

Answer (score 0):

So don't do it with table because it do not make any sense, and do not put div in a table anyway. It's not recommended at all.

Do it with div like this :

```
<div runat="server" style="float:left; overflow:hidden; display:block">

    <div class="item">
        <iframe width="370" height="210" src="<%#Eval("VideoLink") %>">       
        <span class="description"><%#Eval("VideoDesc") %></span>
    </div>

</div>
```

and in a css stylesheet

```
.server {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row-wrap;
}

.server .item {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.server .item .description {
    display: block;
}
```

It should do the job

Comment: This came close, but the video and the description are side-by-side.  I was hoping to get the description directly under the video, and have the next video/description pair next to them.

Comment: add display: block; to .description

Comment: That didn't change anything, unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry, set max-width: 370px on .item